# Drupal Content type Booking Page

Tags: nodes, commerce, google-analytics, bookings

Currently, I have a single booking page (`Booking content type`) in Drupal. For example `www.xyz.com/booking` and booking page itself is handling error and confirmation page and falls on same URL `www.xyz.com/booking`. Few Question needs to be considered

1) For google analytics, it's how to track we booking is successful or got an error since we are using same URL `www.xyz.com/booking`? How can we setup google analytics with same `/booking` URL for confirmation and error page and normal booking page?

2) If I want to divide those two pages using two different content type 
for example booking `confirmation page - www.xyz.com/booking-confirm` and `booking error www.xyz.com/booking-error`. I can easily solve google analytics issue. Does that make sense to creating two different content type for booking error handling and for comfirmation? Any other alternative solution to resolve the issue of google analytics and error, confirmation booking page?

Comment: Are you sure you're not confusing Content types and Nodes of those Content types? You don't have to create new Content types just to create "confirm" or "error" pages. You can create them from Basic page Content type, or Booking if it's better suited in your case. It is common practice to have separate pages for different steps in processes to Google Analytics can track steps easily.

Comment: Great! Thank you for response @prkos and Content types and node of Content types are different and not confusing on it.

Comment: should I use node of Booking (content types) here? That's what it is about?

Comment: Yes, you can use Booking Content type to create node Error and node Confirmation. I guess it depends on which fields you have on that Content type. For Google Analytics it's easiest to have all those steps on separate pages/nodes. It doesn't have to be Booking Content type, it can be Basic page Content type for example, just have separate nodes.

Comment: Thank you @prkos really appreciated! I will ping you here. if I have any other doubts on this. Thank you again.

Comment: I'm glad to help :)

Comment: I have created two node using "Confirm" and "Error" using Booking Content Type. Should I have hook them into `template.php`. I have booking class and booking php. Should I use header to redirect them?